# Can I programmatically find the position of a handle in a JTree row?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Can I programmatically find the position of a handle in a `JTree` row?

By the handle I mean that little knob which, if single-clicked, expands/collapse its corresponding `JTree` row.

Comment: please with selection or without selection, focused or not

Comment: @mKorbel at this stage any advice will do

Comment: Why not use a `TreeExpansionListener`?

Comment: @trashgod I'm using the AWT Robot and trying to point the mouse on that handle.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm using the AWT `Robot` and trying to point the mouse on that handle.*

As it is controlled by the tree's UI delegate, typically a subclass of `BasicTreeUI`, the geometry varies from one L&F to the next. Absent a more general approach, you may be able to test/demonstrate the required functionality using some combination of the programatic navigation methods.

- `setRootVisible()`
- `expandRow()`
- `setSelectedValue()`
- `setSelectionPath()`
- `scrollPathToVisible()`
- `scrollRowToVisible()`